# sed multiline search and replace: delete and append second matching line to first

Tags: sed

I have some lines in a file that got modified by some java program and the lines containing `'\n'` got split into 2 lines automatically. I want to use `sed` to modify them back.

Requirement: Search for only matching lines. Delete the second line and append to previous one.

```
Eg:
line 1: LINES TERMINATED BY '
line 2: '  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT

Output Expected:
line 1: LINES TERMINATED BY ''  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
```

So first search for these word sequence in consequent lines and then delete the second and append to first.

Solution I tried:

```
sed -e "/LINES TERMINATED BY '/N;s/'  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT/LINES TERMINATED BY ''  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT/ external_revenue.sql > myfile_new.txt
```

This modifies the second line but doesn't delete and append it to the first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following `sed` program appears to work.  I've underscored the literal strings for *line 1* and *line 2*:

```
/LINES TERMINATED BY '$/{N;s/\n\('  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT\)/\1/;}
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

### Break-down

Match *line 1*:

```
/LINES TERMINATED BY '$/{N;s/\n\('  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT\)/\1/;}
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Run all of the commands in the block between `{` and `}` on match:

```
/LINES TERMINATED BY '$/{N;s/\n\('  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT\)/\1/;}
                        ^                                       ^
```

First command: append next line (i.e. *line 2*) to current pattern space (i.e. append to end of *line 1*).  Following the append, the pattern space will include a newline separator between *line 1* and *line 2*:

```
/LINES TERMINATED BY '$/{N;s/\n\('  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT\)/\1/;}
                         ^
```

Second command: replace first (and only) occurrences of "newline followed by *line 2*" with just "*line 2*" (i.e. remove the newline):

```
/LINES TERMINATED BY '$/{N;s/\n\('  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT\)/\1/;}
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If the `s///` does not match, the newline from *line 1* is preserved, and the pattern space (*line 1* '\n' *line 2*) is output as-is essentially preserving both lines without modification.

### Quoting for `bash`

```
'/LINES TERMINATED BY '"'"'$/{N;s/\n\('"'"'  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT\)/\1/;}'
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ~~~ ^^^^^^^^^^^ ~~~ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Characters highlighted with `^` are preserved using single-quotes.  The patterns highlighted with `~` introduce a literal single-quote `'` in the string.

---

---

### Alternative solution

If your `sed` supports the `-z` option, you should be able to do it like this:

```
sed -z -e 's/LINES TERMINATED BY '"'"'\n'"'"'  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT/LINES TERMINATED BY '"''"'  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT/g' external_revenue.sql > myfile_new.txt
```

Using `-z` (NUL separated data) allows matching of newlines (using `\n'`) directly in the search regexp.

---

Sample `external_revenue.sql`:

```
LINES OK
LINES TERMINATED BY '
'  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
LINES OK
LINES OK
LINES TERMINATED BY '
'  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
LINES OK
```

Terminal session:

```
$ sed -z -e 's/LINES TERMINATED BY '"'"'\n'"'"'  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT/LINES TERMINATED BY '"''"'  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT/g' external_revenue.sql 
LINES OK
LINES TERMINATED BY ''  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
LINES OK
LINES OK
LINES TERMINATED BY ''  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
LINES OK
```

Comment: I did downvote because 1) `-z` is unnecessary here, and it's not portable, 2) you haven't explained what is wrong with OP's attempt

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for responding.  Can you post an answer that addresses your points?

Comment: No, I do not answer low-quality questions with no visible research effort. OP could have figured this out on their own by just looking up the manual, it wouldn't take more than a minute. Though [so] policy *advices* otherwise, I just downvote such questions and equally low-quality answers given to them

Comment: Try improving your answer and I'll retract the vote.

Comment: @rtx13 thanks for the answer. But unfortunately my `sed` version doesn't support `-z`.

Comment: @oguzismail I tried reading the manual, but it was not as simple to me as to you. I spent 2-3 hours yesterday on this. Also I am no bash expert.

Comment: @oguzismail, I don't follow. Are you saying I just ditch the `/N` and use `\n` like the example shown by rtx13. I had already tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: @Ashu No, read the manual again, `/N` is not a command, `N` is, and `\n` is a character. You're looking for something like `sed -e "/LINES TERMINATED BY '/N;s/\n//"`

Comment: @oguzismail, thanks `sed -e "/LINES TERMINATED BY '/N;s/\n//" external_revenue.sql > myfile_new.txt` worked for me. But what if I also wanted to match the starting words from second line before replacing?

Comment: @Ashu figure it out yourself. Have fun

Comment: @rtx13 I had figured out the answer after discussion with oguzismail. It matches exactly with yours. But thanks for the detailed explanation. I will mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: @oguzismail, I found this link https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-35 very detailed manual, now I know why you said, I could figure it out on my own :)  . Earlier I was only looking at man page.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ":a;N;s/'\n'/''/;ta;P;D" file
```

Form a running window of two lines.

If the end of the first line is `'` and the start of the second line is `'`, remove the newline inbetween and repeat until there are no further matches.

Print/Delete the first line and repeat.

Comment: Thanks this also looks like an elegant solution. I will try it out.